# Adding and removing class in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, removeclass

I'm trying to show/hide my div elements using `slidetoggle` and `slideDown`. Its working perfectly fine.
Now what I'm trying to do is, I want to `addClass` 'visible-divs' to the visible divs only and `removeClass`when they get hidden.

Problem is, the class is added succesfully but it doesn't remove the class when it `slides up` to hide them. What am I doing wrong?

```js
$(".OffersContainer > div:gt(0)").hide();
    
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function() {
    this.clickCount = (this.clickCount || 0) + 1
    var command = this.clickCount % 3 === 0 ? 'slideToggle' : 'slideDown';
    $(this).siblings(this.clickCount % 3 === 1 ? "div:lt(3)" : "div:gt(0)")[command]();
    $('.pan-box').filter(':visible').addClass("visible-divs");
    $('.pan-box').filter(':hidden').removeClass("visible-divs");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'>A</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>B</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>C</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>D</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>E</div>
    <span>Show more</span>
</div>
```

Comment: please add relevant code to OP

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For this to work you need to select the `:visible`/`:hidden` elements *after* the animation completes. To do this, use the callback function parameter:

```
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function() {
    this.clickCount = (this.clickCount || 0) + 1
    var command = this.clickCount % 3 === 0 ? 'slideToggle' : 'slideDown';
    $(this).siblings(this.clickCount % 3 === 1 ? "div:lt(3)" : "div:gt(0)")[command](function() {
        $('.pan-box').filter(':visible').addClass("visible-divs");
        $('.pan-box').filter(':hidden').removeClass("visible-divs");
    });
});
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/qo55rmuy/8/)

As an aside, what's the point of changing a class on a hidden element? By definition the effect won't be seen. You can just use the `:hidden` selector alone if you want to know which elements are hidden

Comment: Later in my code I have applied some logic on those divs which have class `visible-divs` . Therefore I need to get rid of this class once the divs get hidden.

Comment: Exactly - my point is you could just use `:visible` instead of having to maintain the state of a class attribute

Comment: He can also add/remove the class before the animation, think that's what he wants. Otherwise, he would need to place all incoming code inside the callback function.

Comment: @skobaljic he was originally doing that, which is why the `:hidden` elements never had their classes removed.

Comment: Yes, but he did it wrong way, by checking if element is visible. It can be done other way.

Comment: How? The element will be visible until the animation finishes, hence why you have to use the callback

Comment: Ok, I shall add another answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to wait for animation to finish, since you already know which options to hide or show, than you can use this code:

```js
$(".OffersContainer > div:gt(0)").hide();
$(".OffersContainer > span").click(function() {
    this.clickCount = (this.clickCount || 0) + 1
    var command = this.clickCount % 3 === 0 ? 'slideToggle' : 'slideDown';
    $(this).siblings(this.clickCount % 3 === 1 ? "div:lt(3)" : "div:gt(0)")[command]();
    console.log(this.clickCount % 3 * 3 - 1);
    $('.pan-box:lt(' + (this.clickCount % 3 * 3) + ')').addClass("visible-divs");
    $('.pan-box:gt(' + (this.clickCount % 3 * 3) + ')').removeClass("visible-divs");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="OffersContainer">
    <div class='pan-box'>A</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>B</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>C</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>D</div>
    <div class='pan-box'>E</div>
    <span>Show more</span>
</div>
```

Also on **[JSFiddle playground](https://jsfiddle.net/qo55rmuy/11/)**.